# Mysql 8 INSERT performance degradation with bin-log

Tags: mysql

I have a setup using PHP/MySQL running on MySQL 5.
I have moved this setup to a MySQL 8 based install and suffered severe degradation in INSERT performance.
A typical INSERT takes 40ms.
Tabels are identical and queries are identical.
SELECT perfomance is as good or better.

The performance difference is repeatedly about 100 times slower on MySQL 8 at INSERT.

I have changed innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit =2.

This improved somewhat with to typical INSERT to 10ms.

Then I disabled bin-log. This gave a significant performance boost.

Insert is now about 0.5 ms, and I believe to be acceptable, as it is not a heavy traffic db.

The question now is:
Is it normal to have this difference in performance due to bin-log?
If not, what should be expected, and what are the likely candidates to improve this?
Is it safe to disable bin-log, given that I do not have db replication?

Comment: What is the value of `sync_binlog`?

Comment: What is the value of `sync_binlog`?

Comment: sync_binlog is set to 1

Comment: and binlog_group_commit_sync_delay=0 @Rick James

Comment: "=1" adds some I/O overhead.

Answer (score 1):

The binary log does have a pretty high performance overhead. https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/05/04/how-binary-logs-affect-mysql-8-0-performance/ shows that the overhead is up to 30%.

The binary log is used for replication as you know, and it can also be used for [point-in-time recovery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/point-in-time-recovery.html) if you combine it with backups. It's up to you if this is useful to you or if you want to disable binary logs.

I'll comment that as a consultant, I have been called by a few clients who had a database server crash when their storage device died. I asked if they had working backups or binary logs, and they said no. All I could say was, "then I hope that data wasn't important."

There's a compromise solution: you can keep `sync_binlog` but use a value other than 1. The value is not a boolean or ON/OFF, it's an integer. It means "every 1 transactions, sync the binlog file to disk." You can set this to a higher value, for example 100, so it runs a sync to disk on every 100th commit. This obviously isn't as secure as syncing after every commit, but it's often better than just allowing the filesystem to buffer writes until it feels like syncing.

Another strategy is to use replication, with semi-synchronous replication so the replica is guaranteed to receive the binlog event, even if it isn't synced to disk on the primary or the replica. Replicating a binary log event over a local network is fast, and is often faster than syncing it to disk.

One more comment: If your disk performance is important, you should explore options for upgrading the hardware to support fast sync. If you are still using rotational disks, consider updating to SSD or NVMe technology.